# importação de script na ordem errada, function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import

Eu tenho um component vue (`Map.vue`):

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import '../../assets/js/map.js'

export default {
    name: 'home',
    data () {
        return {
            init_data: {},
        }
    },
    created: function() {
         this.init_data = window.get_init_data(this.view, function(response) {
               document.title = response.body.page_title;
               init_map(some_arguments); // erro aqui
         });
    }
}
</script>
```

map.js:

```
const key = ******;
function init_map(some_args) {
    ...
}
```

Erro:

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: init_map is not
>   defined"

E de facto, inspecionando que o codigo fonte a função está a ser chamada antes da sua assinatura.

Nota: Eu não quero incluir `map.js` nas minhas entradas do webpack porque só vou precisar deste script num componente.

Comment: o problema é que o `created: function(){}` roda antes do map.js ser carregado. você terá de encontrar outro método que rode depois do map.js ser carregado, imagino que seria algo como `ready: function(){}`

Answer (score 2):

Acabei por conseguir fazendo:

Map.vue:

```
<script>
import init_map from '../../assets/js/map.js';
...
</script>
```

map.js

```
const key = ******;
export default function init_map(some_args) {
    ...
}
```